# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected token < but not in incognito mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, plugins, token

I've searching my html and javascript for a loose "<" and I couldn't find it. Someone told me to try incognito mode, it could be  a conflict with an ext or plugin.
Sure enough, it worked. 
I still have not found out what caused this or how I can fix it. Any advice would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Try disabling your extensions and enabling one by one again. That's your best call IMHO.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace, that comes from an extension.